# Когда выполнять Dispose контекста?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, orm

Читаю код одного web-приложения (ASP.NET MVC). В нем для доступа к данным используется Entity Framework.  Есть класс Repository который заключает в себе логику работы с EF. Сам DbContext создается "лениво" по первому обращению к нему. Класс Repository реализует интерфейс IDisposable, в котором происходит вот что:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
    MyContext.Dispose();
}
```

То есть на протяжении работы с репозиторием вплоть до его Dispose изменения в бд накапливаются, а сохраняются уже при вызове Dispose. Сам же репот\зиторий диспозится по окончании запроса:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {           
        Repository.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Вроде бы логично - во время жизни запроса жив и репозиторий, и он накапливает изменения в бд, а по окончании запроса изменения пишутся в бд. Вроде бы логично - мы не дергаем на каждый чих метод SaveChanges, а пишем всё один раз (при необходимости сделать изменения здесь и сейчас такая возможность тоже есть).

Однако везде я вижу вот такое использование контекста:

```
using(var ctx = new DbContext())
{
    // код работы с бд
}
```

То есть контекст диспозится сразу же, и сразу же сохраняются изменения. 
То есть подхода, описанного выше, я нигде, кроме как в этом коде не видел. 
Насколько он правилен и нет ли у него каких-то недостатков по сравнению с использованием `using` сразу же?

Comment: что мешает в этом случае вместо DbContext использовать класс Repository? и будет то же самое

Comment: `Repository` - чей?

Comment: @Igor Repository самописный, он инкапсулирует логиу работы с бд через EF.

Comment: @Pupkin `Repository` это объект? Кто его создает, кому он принадлежит?